# Android mediaplayer release block

Tags: android

Play local video, click the next frequently, sometime anr happed

```
06-27 09:22:32.597  1698  1703 I dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-27 09:22:32.647   768   782 E ActivityManager: ANR in com.fourtech.amusic (com.fourtech.amusic/com.startgallery.VideoMain)
06-27 09:22:32.647   768   782 E ActivityManager: PID: 1389
06-27 09:22:32.647   768   782 E ActivityManager: Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting because the touched window has not finished processing the input events that were previously delivered to it.)
06-27 09:22:32.647   768   782 E ActivityManager: Load: 6.24 / 3.12 / 1.23
06-27 09:22:32.647   768   782 E ActivityManager: CPU usage from 1177ms to -4252ms ago:
06-27 09:22:32.647   768   782 E ActivityManager:   30% 1483/com.aispeech.aios: 21% user + 8.4% kernel / faults: 3203 minor 6 major
06-27 09:22:32.647   768   782 E ActivityManager:   19% 768/system_server: 14% user + 4.9% kernel / faults: 1472 minor 18 major
06-27 09:22:32.647   768   782 E ActivityManager:   14% 1897/com.android.systemui: 10% user + 4% kernel / faults: 3229 minor 4 major
```

the anr file:

```
----- pid 1389 at 2017-06-27 09:22:28 -----
Cmd line: com.fourtech.amusic

JNI: CheckJNI is off; workarounds are off; pins=1; globals=373

DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)

"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x415cde58 self=0x414e9538
  | sysTid=1389 nice=-8 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073967444
  | state=S schedstat=( 20891863233 3762682489 22894 ) utm=1566 stm=523 core=5
  #00  pc 00020774  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
  #01  pc 0002d313  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
  #02  pc 0001d3ed  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+140)
  #03  pc 0001d8d7  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::waitForResponse(android::Parcel*, int*)+42)
  #04  pc 0001dadf  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::transact(int, unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+118)
  #05  pc 00019791  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::BpBinder::transact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+30)
  #06  pc 000577c5  /system/lib/libmedia.so
  #07  pc 00055321  /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::MediaPlayer::disconnect()+48)
  #08  pc 0001a555  /system/lib/libmedia_jni.so
  #09  pc 000204cc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
  #10  pc 00051157  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
  #11  pc 00029960  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #12  pc 00030dec  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
  #13  pc 0002e484  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
  #14  pc 0006389d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+392)
  #15  pc 0006b7a3  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #16  pc 00029960  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #17  pc 00030dec  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
  #18  pc 0002e484  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
  #19  pc 000635b9  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
  #20  pc 0004cd37  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #21  pc 0004e00b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
  #22  pc 0004ed2f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+354)
  #23  pc 0000105b  /system/bin/app_process
  #24  pc 0000e53b  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+50)
  #25  pc 00000d7c  /system/bin/app_process
   at android.media.MediaPlayer._release(Native Method)
   at android.media.MediaPlayer.release(MediaPlayer.java:1359)
   at com.startgallery.VideoMain.playStart(VideoMain.java:313)
   at com.startgallery.VideoMain.onItemClick(VideoMain.java:1383)
   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
   at com.fourtech.widget.PagedListView$1.onClick(PagedListView.java:887)
```

the backtrace analysis:

```
-- __ioctl.S:9 __ioctl
-- ioctl.c:41 ioctl
-- IPCThreadState.cpp:848 android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)
-- IPCThreadState.cpp:710 android::IPCThreadState::waitForResponse(android::Parcel*, int*)
-- IPCThreadState.cpp:602 android::IPCThreadState::transact(int, unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)
-- BpBinder.cpp:165 android::BpBinder::transact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)
-- IMediaPlayer.cpp:77 android::BpMediaPlayer::disconnect()
-- mediaplayer.cpp:86 android::MediaPlayer::disconnect()
-- android_media_MediaPlayer.cpp:675 android_media_MediaPlayer_release
-- CallEABI.S:258 dvmPlatformInvoke
-- Jni.cpp:1159 dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)
-- InterpAsm-armv7-a-neon.S:16314 dalvik_mterp
-- Mterp.cpp:105 dvmMterpStd(Thread*)
-- Interp.cpp:1961 dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)
-- Stack.cpp:737 dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)
-- java_lang_reflect_Method.cpp:101 Dalvik_java_lang_reflect_Method_invokeNative
-- InterpAsm-armv7-a-neon.S:16314 dalvik_mterp
-- Mterp.cpp:105 dvmMterpStd(Thread*)
-- Interp.cpp:1961 dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)
-- Stack.cpp:526 dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)
-- Jni.cpp:2097 CallStaticVoidMethodV
-- jni.h:780 _JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)
-- AndroidRuntime.cpp:891 android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)
-- app_main.cpp:231 (discriminator 3) main
-- libc_init_dynamic.cpp:112 __libc_init
-- libgcc2.c:? _start
```

from logcat, we can see MediaPlayer._release, from the backtrace analysis, after call is mediaplayer.cpp disconnect func

it may be disconnect blocked

Comment: Hi Guomin, welcome to SO. Please take a moment and look into this to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: OK, I'll take a good look at it
This is my first question